# Compute centroids and buffers for multiple polygons in Google Earth Engine

Tags: polygon, buffer, centroids, google-fusion-tables, google-earth-engine

I have a dataset with many polygons that come from a fusion table ('xxxxx'):

`var polygons = ee.FeatureCollection('xxxxx');`

I want to compute the centroid and a buffer of Z meters for each of these polygons. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The task you are asking to do is termed `mapping over a FeatureCollection` in Google Earth Engine. You can see GEE documentation on doing so [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/feature_collection_mapping).

To compute the tasks you want, you can write small functions that append the centroid coordinates for each feature as an attribute, or return a FeatureCollection with the specified buffer:

```js
var polygons = ee.FeatureCollection('xxxxx');

var getCentroids = function(feature) {
  return feature.set({polyCent: feature.centroid()});
};

var bufferPoly = function(feature) {
  return feature.buffer(Z);   // substitute in your value of Z here
};

var fcWithCentroids = polygons.map(getCentroids);
print(fcWithCentroids) // access the features and look at the properties, for which there should be a point with the centroid coords

var bufferedPolys = polygons.map(bufferPoly);
Map.addLayer(bufferedPolys, {}, 'Buffered polygons');
Map.addLayer(polygons, {}, 'Unbuffered polygons'); // for comparison
```

There may be more elegant ways of getting the map function to return both tasks with a single go, but I'll let you explore how to do that as it will be a good learning experience!